# Regex to match string pattern in multi lines

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract text from pdf. But the extracted text is not in order. So i am writing regex to extract and use it. As i am new in writing regex and with handling multilines in text i am facing issues. Could some one help. 
The String text is like this:
stringtext = 0,10 - 0,20 0,30 - 0,40, 0,50 - 0,60 (Line 1)
A (Line 2)
/ (Line 3)
B (Line 4)
/ (Line 5)
C (Line 6)
/ (Line 7)
D (Line 8)
/ (Line 9)

My aim to extract only A B C D from string text. Could some one help. Thanks!

I tried researching but i am not able to find a solution that suits me.

```
    stringtext = 0,10 - 0,20 0,30 - 0,40, 0,50 - 0,60
                 A
                 /
                 B
                 /
                 C
                 /
                 D
                 /;
   Pattern pattern = pattern.compile(".*\\r\\n(\\_.*)$");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringtext);
   if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1);
   }
```

Expected output should be A B C D

Comment: Try `stringtext.substring(s.indexOf("\n")).trim().split("\\s*/\\s*")`

Comment: @DelMub Did that work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `.*` to match the first line, you might make the match a bit more specific by starting it with for example the pattern of the first number.

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to get repetitive matches and match the uppercase characters in a capturing group.

```
(?:^\d+,\d+.*|\G(?!^))\R\h+([A-Z])\R.*\/
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^\d+,\d+.*` Match from the start of the string 1+ digits, comma and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\R\h+` Match unicode newline sequence and 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
- `([A-Z])` Capture an uppercase char in group 1
- `\R.*\/` Match unicode newline sequence, any char except newline 0+ times and a forward slash.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LOKu6B/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/mMpW2v)

For example:

```
String regex = "(?:^\\d+,\\d+.*|\\G(?!^))\\R\\h+([A-Z])\\R.*\\/";
String stringtext = "0,10 - 0,20 0,30 - 0,40, 0,50 - 0,60\n"
     + "                     A\n"
     + "                     /\n"
     + "                     B\n"
     + "                     /\n"
     + "                     C\n"
     + "                     /\n"
     + "                     D\n"
     + "                     /;";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringtext);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: fourth bid: It worked thanks. I tested it yesterday.